# .NET library for PostegreSQL notify/listen

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, notify, listen

Is there any .NET library which can be used to listen to the notifications coming from PostgreSQL?

Npgsql has removed this support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Npgsql definitely hasn't removed support for LISTEN/NOTIFY (although the API has changed somewhat over recent versions): http://www.npgsql.org/doc/wait.html